# Fitness HISTORY_API - how to set account name for client connection

Tags: android, google-api, wear-os, google-fit

I am trying to access google fit data from Android smartwatch from service. For this purpose I am using com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0 and GoogleApiClient for connection:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .useDefaultAccount()
            //.setAccountName("xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com")
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    ....etc..
                    ....etc..
```

In case if I use my own email hardcoded in setAccountName (same account as I use for phone and paired with smartwatch), then it works fine. I am connected with success and function Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal returns steps count correctly.

In case if I'm using useDefaultAccount(), then I am connected with success as well, but Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal returns 0 steps.

**How can I get account name in code for setAcountName() method or useDefaultAccount() method properly?** What I'm missing here in order to make it work?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts on your device or just the one you tried to use hardcoded?

Comment: I have a single account on my device and that's one I try to use hardcoded and it works with setAccountName. I would like to make this generic for any user who will install my app on the smartwatch.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name on the account using a simple GET request as per the official GFit [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/get).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/dataSources/dataSourceId
```

The `dataSourceId` and the `userId` would be the two required parameters that would lead to get the name on the account.